# "falha de rede" ao fazer o download de PDF gerado com com a classe FPDF do PHP no Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, fpdf

Tenho relatórios com gerados em **PHP** (versão 5.6) / [**FPDF**](http://www.fpdf.org/) (versão 1.7) que estão sendo exibidos normalmente na janela do browser.

Segue exemplo simplificado sobre estes relatórios são gerados:

```
<?php
 // não fazer cache (Recomendação de Guilherme Nascimento)
 $dategmt = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
 header('Expires: ' . $dategmt . ' GMT');
 header('Last-Modified: ' . $dategmt . ' GMT');
 header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');


// controla se o usuário pode ter acesso ao relatório
require 'controle-acesso.php';
if(!userTemAcesso()){
   echo 'Você não tem permissões para acessar este recurso';
   exit;
}

require 'fpdf.php';

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Olá mundo!');

// saída para arquivo não acessível diretamente via URL
$this->Output('doc.pdf', 'I');
```

Nota:

- Os parâmetros são passados para o PHP que gera o relatório via `POST`.
- O arquivo está sendo acessado exclusivamente via HTTPS com certificado válido.
- O servidor web está habilitado para logar todos os erros e os erros estão sendo devidamente registrados no log, porém nenhum erro relacionado a este PHP está sendo registrado. (ou seja, eu limpo o log de erros, executo o relatório e nenhum erro aparece no log... forçando um erro propositalmente e o mesmo é registrado). Desta forma, parece que não há qualquer erro de sintaxe.
- O `Content-type` utilizado é: `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`
- O problema ocorre em computadores dom Windws e Google Chrome (testado em várias máquinas).
- Usando plugin nativo do Google Chrome (chrome://plugins/ -> Chrome PDF Viewer). Se eu desativo ele, fica fazendo download normal do arquivo. Se ativo, ele visualiza tudo normal, imprime, porém não funciona a opção SALVAR.

Todos os botões do plug-In de exibição de PDF dos browsers (salvar, imprimir, girar, zoom, etc.) funcionam normalmente. **Exceto** o **botão salvar** no Google Chrome (nos outros browsers funciona normal).

Ao tentar salvar o PDF aberto e já exibido no Google Chrome, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Falha - Erro na rede

Logo, não é possível salvar o PDF, a não ser que vá em imprimir e imprima em PDF, ou seja, imprimir o PDF em PDF, o que não faz muito sentido.

**Alguém teria alguma ideia ou sugestão como resolver este erro ou do que poderia estar causando o mesmo?**

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo básico do código? Não fui eu quem negativou, mas acredito que quem deu o downvote tenha tido este motivo.

Comment: Não tem sentido o `Output('I', '/var/tmp/relatorio.pdf');`, o `I` serve para colocar o buffer no output diretamente, se quer salvar em um arquivo use `F`, se quiser download use `D` e se quiser obter o buffer em uma string use `S`

Comment: Mas isso também esta errado `$this->Output('doc.pdf', 'I');`, você mudou a ordem por que? Veja os exemplos na resposta (eu editei).

Comment: está assim na classe FPDF:  function Output($name = '', $dest = '') {

Comment: Allan que versão você baixou?

Comment: Allan qual plugin está usando no chrome, é o nativo dele (PDF Viewer) ou é o AcrobatReader ou FoxitReader?

Comment: O nativo dele: chrome://plugins/  -> Chrome PDF Viewer  (se eu desativo ele, fica fazendo download normal do arquivo.) Se ativo, ele visualiza tudo normal, imprime, porém não funciona a opção SALVAR.

Comment: Blz, vou fazer os testes.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema seja com o cache

- Você pode fazer *prevenir o cache*, adicione isto ao topo:

  > O `I` no método `Output` já adiciona o header `application/pdf` e envia o buffer diretamente para o buffer

  ```php
  <?php

  // controla se o usuário pode ter acesso ao relatório
  require 'controle-acesso.php';

  if (!userTemAcesso()) {
     echo 'Você não tem permissões para acessar este recurso';
     exit;
  }

  require 'fpdf.php';

  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
  $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Olá mundo!');
  $pdf->Output('I', 'meuarquivo.pdf'); //versão 1.8
  //$pdf->Output('meuarquivo.pdf', 'I'); //versão 1.7
  ```
- O `I` já previne o cache, mas se ainda não funcionar pode tentar assim:

  ```php
  <?php

  $dategmt = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');

  header('Expires: ' . $dategmt . ' GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . $dategmt . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');

  // controla se o usuário pode ter acesso ao relatório
  require 'controle-acesso.php';

  if (!userTemAcesso()) {
     echo 'Você não tem permissões para acessar este recurso';
     exit;
  }

  require 'fpdf.php';

  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
  $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Olá mundo!');
  $pdf->Output('I', 'meuarquivo.pdf'); //versão 1.8
  //$pdf->Output('meuarquivo.pdf', 'I'); //versão 1.7
  ```
- Você pode salvar no servidor e redirecionar:

  ```php
  <?php

  // controla se o usuário pode ter acesso ao relatório
  require 'controle-acesso.php';

  if(!userTemAcesso()){
     echo 'Você não tem permissões para acessar este recurso';
     exit;
  }

  require 'fpdf.php';

  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
  $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Olá mundo!');
  $pdf->Output('F', '/home/user/www/data/meuarquivo.pdf'); //versão 1.8
  //$pdf->Output('/home/user/www/data/meuarquivo.pdf', 'F'); //versão 1.7

  //Redireciona
  header('Location: data/meuarquivo.pdf');
  ```

### Parâmetros:

O método `Output` tem 4 opções:

- `I`:

  Exibe o buffer diretamente na resposta (por exemplo no browser) com se fosse um PDF usando `Content-Type: application/pdf`
- `F`:

  Salva o arquivo em uma pasta no servidor
- `D`:

  Força o download do buffer
- `S`:

  Retorna o buffer como uma `string`

Comment: Se eu redirecionar, como controlo a permissão de acesso?

Comment: @AllanAndrade basta adicionar a permissões na pasta `data` 755 (note que é uma pasta de exemplo), se permissão você quer dizer nivel de acesso por autenticação você pode criar um token e colocar como o nome do arquivo.

Comment: @AllanAndrade atualizei o código